# NetSuite - How to add new base Currency?

Tags: netsuite, currency, finance

I need to add a new base currency (SEK) into our NetSuite system.
I'm able to find those that are already configured as USD, Euro, Canadian Dolar..but I can't find where to add a new base currency.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the currencies page and press the "New" button.

Type `currencies` in the global search and select `Page: Currencies` from the list that comes up so you can review the current ones before adding another. As well on this page click on the `? Help` button and review the topic that comes up (Currency Management) and it's sub topics.

If the page mentioned in the previous paragraph doesn't come up or the `New` button doesn't appear then the role/account you are logged into doesn't have the permissions required to add new currencies.